Is it possible to invert root and tip from hair strands?
I'm using an addon called hair net to convert hair cards to particles in blender, however, some of the strand turn out to be inverted (some tips are roots)
In the attached picture, you will see it. Red dots are tips and blue ones are dots
Thanks in advance

